# Remotely diagnosing server 2012 boot problems with no KVM

Tags: windows, logging, windows-server-2012, boot

I have a rented dedicated server that seems to have run into some issues. Unfortunately I have rented from a company who will only give hardware support leaving me in the dark. My server had been running happily for three months with no reboot and nothing extra installed since the last reboot. Last night I received an email saying that the server had gone offline and it had been booted into a recovery OS (WinPE). I have attempted to reboot into windows only to have the same thing happen again with the server never coming online thus making me think it will no longer boot. The ideal would be to turn on boot logging but as I cannot access it pre-boot (The F8 boot menu) I don't know of another way to turn on boot logging. I have full access to the disk of the server and should be able to gain access to the registry. I can remotely reinstall the OS but obviously I don't want to loose what was a weeks worth of work configuring the server.

Literally any ideas on this would be a great help I'm banging my head against the wall and looking at the reinstall button with disgust.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you can download files from your servers hard drive.

Try this:

Grab your BCD file from your servers boot partition.

then run:

```
bcdedit /set bootlog yes /store <path-to-bcd-file>
```

restore bcd file to appropriate path and reboot server with fingers crossed ;)

Comment: Not quite sure whats going on - C:\>bcdedit /set bootlog yes /store D:\BCD
An error occurred while attempting to reference the specified entry.
The system cannot find the file specified. The file is definitely there, any clues?